# Check if something is in a list multiple times?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I have a dictionary of monsters, which I get enemies from by choosing a random integer and matching it to the first number in the dictionary value (it's a list)

```
#NAME: ID, HP, MP, ATK, DEF, MGATK, MGDEF, SPEED, EXPSHARE, IMG
monsters_list = {"BOXROACH": [1, 20, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, pg.image.load("boxcroach.png")],

for i in range(amt):
            monster = random.randint(1, len(self.monsters))
            for key in self.monsters:
                if self.monsters[key][0] == monster:
                    monsters.append([key, self.monsters[key]])
```

So amt is a number between 1 and 3 which decides how many monsters will be facing, and then it goes through the dictionary to match the first index of the value and then append the monster to a list, which ends up looking like this:

```
[['SLUGGER', [2, 20, 10, 5, 3, 8, 7, 11, 7, <Surface(150x160x32 SW)>]], ['SLUGGER', [2, 20, 10, 5, 3, 8, 7, 11, 7, <Surface(150x160x32 SW)>]], ['MEAN SPIRIT', [10, 15, 15, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 20, <Surface(100x100x32 SW)>]]]
```

(ignore the dumb names)

What I want to do is to check if there are multiple of the same enemy, and then differentiate them in some way. I was originally going to go through to add all the indexes to another list and then compare them, but is there a more efficient way to do this? Thanks.

Comment: use a `set` ? use a dictionary with names as keys? `monsters[key] = self.monsters[key]` will do

Comment: @Jean-François Fabre THANKS tbh that would be a better idea than just having a list of lists.

Comment: specially since you seem to _know_  about dictionaries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*You can do by:*
**check your random numbers in order to not be the same so your monsters will be different.**

if an random number repeated again do next random number.

and also if you want to different them in some ways it's better to make a monster details class then if they were repeated then change some parameters on there for each monster .